# Why derive a List<T> class just to restate an indexer?

Tags: c#, list, inheritance

I keep seeing List derived classes that look something like this

```
class MyClassList : List<MyClass>
{
    public MyClass this[int index]
    {
        get { return (MyClass)base[index]; }
    }
}
```

What is the point of this inheritance? It looks like it just restates the casting of the member. I could understand other types of indexer, but this is just a restatement of the default List indexer, and provokes a Visual Studio warning RE: hiding of the base indexer. Is this the right or wrong thing to do, and why?

Comment: I dont know where you see such code, but there are millions of things just plain wrong with it!

Comment: where do you keep seeing that? Because I've never seen it. It is a horrible piece of code.

Comment: A guess: Newb coder tried to hide the setter. (lol)

Comment: @flq Alas, it would have been among the zillion tutorials, code samples, how-to-do-blah-blah's that I've pulled up in the last few weeks as I've ramped up my C#. Rest assured, if I find another one, I'll post the link, so that the full fury of SO may be unleashed upon the hapless perpetrator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no good reason for this. It *hides* the base indexer instead of *overriding* it, which could be dangerous, and it doesn't have any effect at all.

In most cases, it's best just to *use* a `List<MyClass>` directly. There's no need to create a special class for this if you're not planning to extend `List<>`'s functionality at all.

Comment: Ok, follow-up to that--if one *is* extending the base, I assume that base indexer should be left alone, correct?

Comment: @downwitch: Yes, unless there is a specific reason to do so. It is possible, for example, that you want to fire an event any time the collection is changed. In that case you would *override* (not hide) the base indexer, causing it to invoke the base indexer and then fire the appropriate event. Or you might decide that after a certain flag is set, no changes are allowed: in this case you would override the base indexer to throw an exception if that flag is set. There are legitimate reasons to override the indexer. There are far fewer reasons to hide it. And in this case, neither applies.

Answer (score 5):

Perhaps it's a *very poor* attempt to prevent the overwriting of values via the indexer?

```
MyClassList x = new MyClassList();
x.Add(new MyClass());
x[0] = new MyClass(); // Error!
```

Of course, it doesn't stop this:

```
List<MyClass> x = new MyClassList();
x.Add(new MyClass());
x[0] = new MyClass(); // No problem here...
```

Basically, it's a bad idea. Poor code abounds, unfortunately - don't infer usefulness from mere existence :(

Answer (score 1):

I don't see any usefulness to doing this.
Also, the cast is unnecessary.

Answer (score 1):

I think it is supposed to hide the `set` accessor of the base class, to make it look like the indexer is read-only. But it's useless, because it's very easy to work around:

```
MyClassList list = ...

((List<MyClass>)list)[index] = value;
```

Anyway, the `List<T>` class isn't designed for inheritance. If you need to create a specialized collection, inherit from `Collection<T>` instead.

Comment: I find your last statement a little confusing. Isn't polymorphism based on the idea that *any* class is designed for inheritance? It seems to me that the number of out-of-the-box methods and the relative ease of reuse of List<T> make it a faster base class to build from. What am I missing?

Comment: What you're missing is that none of the methods in the `List<T>` class are virtual, which makes it impossible to override them. You can always *hide* them, but it's a completely different concept... methods that hide the base class definition won't participate in polymorphism.

Comment: Indeed, that makes very good sense, and as much as I've read on the subject I can remember no one bothering to state that simple dictum: *If a class is designed for inheritance, its methods are virtual*. Perhaps obvious, but not to me.

Answer (score 0):

I've seen this type of stuff before where people want to serialise it out as another type, for now if thats the only code in there and its not required to be of type MyClassList for other reasons, its totally pointless.

Answer (score 0):

this is, basically, a *try* to make correctly override of `[]` access to `List`, to implement some custom element access logic.

Worth mantioned that the code provided *is not good*, if not just *dangerous*. If you want to do somethign tricky with list do not override (or tend to do so) `[]`, but implement some custom method for that purpose.

Answer (score 0):

My guess would be that the code was trying to behave as a read-only `List`.  One would be unable to write to an item of a variable of type `MyClassList<T>` by index, though one would be able to cast it back to `List<T>` and write a variable that way.  There are times when it makes sense to have a variable whose type has limited abilities, hold an object whose actual capabilities are much greater.  The proper way to do that, though, is generally with interfaces, a prime example being `IEnumerable<T>`.  If `List<T>` is passed to a routine which accepts a parameter of type `IEnumerable<T>`, the routine could cast its parameter back to a `List<T>` and use members like `Add()`, `Remove()`, etc. but must routines which accept a parameter of type `IEnumerable<T>` won't try to use it as anything else.

A major problem with the style of code shown by the original poster is that the more 'powerful' direction is the base, rather than the derived type.  Because `List<T>` derives from `IEnumerable<T>`, that means that all instances of `List<T>` can be enumerated, but not only some enumerable things have the extra capabilities in `List<T>`.  By contrast, as your class is implemented, every `MyClassList<T>` can be read and written, but only some instances of `List<T>` can be used as a `MyClassList<T>`.